# How to check if NSDictionary is null and read the JSON value in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, null

I want to check if NSDictionary is NULL or not and read the JSON values.

Here is my code for checking if NSDictionary is null :

```
if ([dataDict objectForKey:@"messages"]!= NULL) {
     NSLog(@"not null");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"null");
}
```

When I print the value for `[dataDict objectForKey:@"messages"]` it's: `messages = "<null>"`

I want to read the JSON value "message": "Not valid." if messages is not null :

```
"messages": {
      "items": [
        {
          "message": "Not valid."
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the output `"<null>"` then this means the value is an instance of `NSNull`. So you need to check for that as well.

I would update your code as follows:

```
id message = dataDict[@"messages"];
if (message == nil || message == [NSNull null]) {
    NSLog("null");
} else {
    NSLog("not null");
    if ([message isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)message;
        NSArray *items = dict[@"items"];
        if (items.count > 0) {
            NSString *message = items[0][@"message"];
            NSLog(@"Message: %@", message);
        }
    }
}
```